# A question involving angle between two vectors.

Tags: vectors

$\hat A+\hat B=2\hat i$ and $\hat A-\hat B=4\hat j$, then the angle between $\hat A$ and $\hat B$ is?

I just don't know how to proceed with this question, so can anyone please just give me a starting clue to continue with?

Answer (score 1):

The angle $\theta$ between two vectors $u$ and $v$ satisfies

$$u\cdot v = \vert\vert u \vert\vert\, \vert\vert v\vert\vert\cos\theta$$
So if we know the values of $\hat A$ and $\hat B$, then we can use the above to find $\theta$. In order to get $\hat A$, add your first equation to the second to get
$$2\hat A = 2\hat i+4\hat j$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Surely ^_^ thanks a lot.